# "Property description must be an object error" in non debug mode while executing command react-native run-android

Tags: android, react-native

I have this react-native project and its been running fine for the past 2 months but now I am getting an error "Property description should be and object" while running the build on android in a non-debug mode. It works very well in debug-mode and on IOS. Can somebody please guide? here is my package.json

Tried downgrading redux to 4.0.0 and put resolutions for babel in package.json. But nothing works and the error persists.

```
  "react-native": "0.58.4",
  "react-native-action-picker": "^1.0.2",
  "react-native-base64": "0.0.2",
  "react-native-cli": "^2.0.1",
  "react-native-color-palette": "^2.0.2",
  "react-native-confirmation-code-input": "^1.0.4",
  "react-native-customized-image-picker": "^0.1.5",
 "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
  "react-navigation": "^2.14.2",
  "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
  "redux": "^4.0.1",
  "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
  "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
  "redux-promise": "^0.6.0",
  "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
```

Answer (score 2):

update npm. redux 4.0.4 work for me

Answer (score -1):

[Just a workaround in case you can't afford to update dependency]
I got the same error in redux, I solved it.

Simply go to: **node_modules/redux/lib/redux.js**

and replace the line:

```
Object.defineProperty(target, key, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(arguments[i], key));
```

to this:

```
var descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(arguments[i], key);
    if (descriptor) {
      Object.defineProperty(target, key, descriptor);
    }
```

Comment: Abdul ..I don't think it would be correct to make a change to node_modules? Would there be another workaround

Comment: This is the only solution I found. If you find any other solution do share with me.

Comment: if your redux version  has become 4.0.3/4.0.2  then uninstall it and install 4.0.1. It will not show the error.